# How can I get a Field Id from a Related Django Model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am working on a Django project where and I want to get an ID of a Related model with a OneToOne attributed so I can edit the profile of the user with his related Profile but all I get in return is **Field 'id' expected a number but got 'GANDE1'**.

Here are my Models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    customer = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    othernames = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=GENDER, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11, null=True)

image = models.ImageField(default='avatar.jpg', blank=False, null=False, upload_to ='profile_images', 

)


#Method to save Image
def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    img = Image.open(self.image.path)
#Check for Image Height and Width then resize it then save
    if img.height > 200 or img.width > 150:
        output_size = (150, 250)
        img.thumbnail(output_size)
        img.save(self.image.path)
        



def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.customer.username}-Profile'

class Account(models.Model):
    customer = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    account_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True) 


    def __str__(self):
        return f' {self.customer} - Account No: {self.account_number}'
```

Here is my Views:

```
def create_account(request): 
#Search Customer
    if searchForm.is_valid():
        #Value of search form
        value = searchForm.cleaned_data['value']
        #Filter Customer by Surname, Othernames , Account Number using Q Objects
        user_filter = Q(customer__exact = value) | Q(account_number__exact = value)
        #Apply the Customer Object Filter
        list_customers = Account.objects.filter(user_filter) 
    
    else:
        list_customers = Account.objects.all()
context = {
    
        'customers':paged_list_customers,
       
    }
    return render(request, 'dashboard/customers.html', context)
```

Here is how I displayed list of accounts in my Template:

```
{% for customer in customers %} 


              <tr>
                <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
                <td>{{ customer.account_number  }}</td> 

                {% if customer.customer.profile.surname == None %}

                <td> <a class="btn btn-danger" href=" {% url 'update-customer' customer.customer.id %} ">Click to Enter Customer Personal Details.</a> </td>

                {% else %}
                
                <td>{{ customer.customer.profile.surname }} {{ customer.customer.profile.othernames }}</td>
                
                <td>{{ customer.customer.profile.phone }}</td>

                <td><a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="{% url 'account-statement' customer.id %}">Statement</a></td>
                
                
                
                <td><a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="{% url 'dashboard-witdrawal' customer.id  %}">Withdraw</a></td>
                


                <th scope="row"><a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="{% url 'create-deposit' customer.id %}">Deposit</a></th>
                {% endif %}
                
                
              </tr>
              {% endfor %}
```

Here is my Customer Update View where I am having issues:

```
def update_customer_profile(request, pk):
#get logged in user
user = request.user
#check if logged in user is staff

try:
    customer_user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
   
except User.DoesNotExist:
    return redirect('user-register')
else:
    count_users = User.objects.count() 
    #Get the Customer User's Profile from the User above
    user_profile = Profile.objects.get(customer=customer_user.username)
```

Please, understand that I want to get the ID of a User and MATCH it with the one in his profile record so I can be able to edit his profile record. And also note that the customer profile is automatically created using signals upon user registration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the `User` object, then simply use the relation between them:

```
try:
    customer_user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
except User.DoesNotExist:
    ...
else:
    ...
    user_profile = customer_user.profile
```

You don't need to query database separately. It's exaclty what relations are for.

Comment: thanks for your answer but here the error I get. View user.view.update_customer_profile didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead. Sir, please understand that the user profile was created automatically using signals and now we want to update it so that is was it returned None. Anticipate your kind response.

Comment: @apollos This is an another issue, I can't do everything, I've just answered the question. It's exaclty what it says - you have to return some response or redirect in every view, in example: return HttpResponse(...). Just please read here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/